# Binaryreader Readint32() returns too big value or -ve value

Tags: c#, networkstream, binaryreader

I am working on client server application where server sends screen image to client using UDT ptotocol. below is my code server sends image using binary-writer and client receive data using binary-writer. Code works perfectly up to few iteration  but after few iteration  reader.ReadInt32() read number which is either too big or either negative. i have read most of the binary-reader related issue but not found any helpful.

Server Code:

```
public void SendImage(Bitmap bmp)
{
   BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(CStream);
       
   using (MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream())
   {
       bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);//save to memory stream 

       long fileSize = ms.Length;
       writer.Write(fileSize); //send length
         
       byte[] buffer = new byte[512 * 1024];
       long pos = 0;
       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

       while (pos < fileSize)
       {
            //If buffer size is smaller then filesize then send in parts
            Int32 toSend = buffer.Length < (fileSize - pos)? buffer.Length: (Int32)(fileSize - pos);
            ms.Read(buffer, 0, toSend); //read from memory stream to byte array
            writer.Write(toSend); 
            ServerSocket.Send(buffer, 0, toSend);
            pos += toSend;

             Console.WriteLine(itration + ", fileSize : "+ fileSize + "," + toSend + ",[buffer]: " + buffer[toSend - 3] + "," + buffer[toSend - 2] + ", " + buffer[toSend-1]);
               
       }
       itration++;
           
       ms.Flush();
       ms.Close();
          }
}
```

Client Side Code:

```
private void startRead()
{
  while (true)
  {
    Bitmap inImage = ReceiveImage(Settings.Encrypted);//BitmapFromStream(Settings.Encrypted);
    theImage.Image = (Image)inImage;
  }
}
private Bitmap ReceiveImage(bool Encrypted)
{
            Bitmap img = null;
            byte[] buffer;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(CStream);
            using(MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    long size = reader.ReadInt64();//read file length first

                    buffer = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024];

                    long read = 0;

                    while (read < size)
                    {
                        int toRecv = reader.ReadInt32(); //here reader reads wrong value

                        Console.WriteLine(itration + "filesize " + size + " Byte to read : " + toRecv);

                        ReadFragment(reader, toRecv, buffer);

                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, toRecv);

                        read += toRecv;
                    }
                    itration++;
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    img = new Bitmap(ms);
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message + " : " + Ex.StackTrace);
                }
                buffer = null;
                ms.Flush();
                ms.Close();
            }
            reader = null;
            return img;
}
private int ReadFragment(BinaryReader reader, int size, byte[] buffer)
{
       int read = 0;
       while (read < size)
       {
           read += reader.Read(buffer, read, size - read);
       }
    return read;
}
```

this is console output from server

```
0, fileSize : 568633,524288,[buffer]: 0,162, 138
0, fileSize : 568633,44345,[buffer]: 31,255, 217
1, fileSize : 568468,524288,[buffer]: 2,138, 40
1, fileSize : 568468,44180,[buffer]: 3,255, 217
2, fileSize : 578806,524288,[buffer]: 198,177, 106
2, fileSize : 578806,54518,[buffer]: 1,255, 217
3, fileSize : 589967,524288,[buffer]: 20,81, 64
3, fileSize : 589967,65679,[buffer]: 15,255, 217

11, fileSize : 632653,524288,[buffer]: 243,255, 0
11, fileSize : 632653,108365,[buffer]: 0,255, 217
12, fileSize : 642562,524288,[buffer]: 205,20, 85
12, fileSize : 642562,118274,[buffer]: 7,255, 217
13, fileSize : 645552,524288,[buffer]: 236,49, 131
13, fileSize : 645552,121264,[buffer]: 0,255, 217
```

and colsole output from client

```
0  filesize 568633 Byte to read : 524288
0  filesize 568633 Byte to read : 44345
1  filesize 568468 Byte to read : 524288
1  filesize 568468 Byte to read : 44180
2  filesize 578806 Byte to read : 524288
2  filesize 578806 Byte to read : 54518
3  filesize 589967 Byte to read : 524288
3  filesize 589967 Byte to read : 65679

11  filesize 632653 Byte to read : 524288
11  filesize 632653 Byte to read : 108365
12  filesize 642562 Byte to read : 524288
12  filesize 642562 Byte to read : 118274
13  filesize 645552 Byte to read : 524288
13  filesize 645552 Byte to read : 671776930 <-- here it read either too big number or negative number
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I have tried binaryformater, protobuf instead of binaryreader but it still stops after few itration.help me find the cause.

Comment: Either the file got corrupted or a extra value was written to the file so the data is shifted.  Check the code that wrote the data to make sure a different value was written.

Comment: ok but how to check if data is currupted or shifted?

Comment: I would suggest separating the code that serializes/deserializes data from the code that sends/receives data over the network. This should allow you to test each separate from each other, and should make problems like this easier to diagnose.

Comment: You need to check the specification of the binary format to see if there should be extra data.  There are 3 possibilities 1) File is corrupted 2)  There should be extra data 3) The program that wrote the data wrote wrong data.  Binary data should have a CRC so when it is transmitted you can tell when it is corrupted.  At work I'm seeing lots of data with bad CRC.  Some is explainable since the transmission mode get change often so we get some CRC errors at beginning of data.  But I'm also seeing some errors in the middle of transmission.